# How can I ORDER BY integer data in a MySQL column with the "longtext" data type?

Tags: mysql, sql

In WordPress, the _postmeta table has a column "meta_value" with the "longtext" data type. However, I'm storing integer data in the column and I want to ORDER BY the column by the integers' value.

For example, if I use "ORDER BY meta_value", the result turns out to be something like this:

```
999
9456
5
123456
111
```

Comment: A better question is, why are you are storing integer data in a text field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CAST (meta_value AS DECIMAL)
```